# TaskGroup `async` vs. `spawn`

Tags: swift, async-await, spawn, swift5

Does anyone know, in the new Swift `async/await` stuff, is there any difference between TaskGroup `async` and `spawn`, or are they pure synonyms? (If they are synonyms, I rather like `spawn` better. `async` looks like we're opening an `async` block, and that's not what we're doing at all.)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/3814850-async

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/3814884-spawn

Comment: I think, `async` might have got deprecated

Comment: @aheze Really? That would be cool. What I saw was that `add` got deprecated, though, so maybe you're thinking of that?

Comment: @Rob Oh nooooze! I was really hoping this would go the other way. The `async` name is so wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SE-0304](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md#review-changes), tells us that `spawn` was renamed `async` as part of the second review:

> - `TaskGroup.spawn` and `TaskGroup.spawnUnlessCancelled` have been renamed to `TaskGroup.async` and `TaskGroup.asyncUnlessCancelled` *which are to be their final names. This aligns the naming with the renamed `async let` as the word signifying creation of a child task.*

The portion in italics has subsequently been removed and the third review has renamed it again:

> - renamed `TaskGroup.async` and `TaskGroup.asyncUnlessCancelled` to `TaskGroup.addTask` and `TaskGroup.addTaskUnlessCancelled`. The fundamental behavior here is that we're adding a task to the group. add by itself does not suffice, because we aren't adding a value (accessible via `next()`), we are adding a task whose value will be accessible via `next()`. It also parallels the use of `Task { ... }` to create top-level tasks.

Comment: I'll wait to see if this actually happens... There are some things in the second review that have not happened in the beta. But I presume they will. :(

Comment: Well they changed free-standing `async` to `Task.init`, but they haven't done anything about TaskGroup `async`. I liked `spawn` or `add` a lot better....

Comment: As I'm sure you know, it’s now `addTask`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's way better.